# HTML/CSS for an infographic page

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm looking to create a web page that incorporates an image of a house - with various parts of the house responsive to mouse clicks. The house would be the single primary element on the page.

Given that I will probably employ an illustrator to make an image, should I:

- try and make it 'box-like' so that I can do it in HTML5/CSS3
- use SVG to get as close to the design as possible
- use an imagemap and Javascript for detecting the clicks on the image

if it was a chart-type infographic, I would use a charting JS library but it's more of a custom image.

Links to informative URLs or example pages would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: This question is both too broad *and* is inviting opinion based answers and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: My only sense of how to narrow the question would be to ask three seperate questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using SVG.
In this way you don't compromise on the quality of the image yet you retain an easy way to 'assign' certain parts of the image to have event handlers attached to them.